# PHP preg_match not working perfectly

Tags: php

In my code I am trying to extract url only from my string using preg_match() function but its not working properly I tried all possible references but nothing works for me.

Here is the string example

```
FileID = "http://downloader.example.com/myfile/Josh.mp4";
```

My Expectation

```
http://downloader.example.com/myfile/Josh.mp4
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$stringURL = "FileID = \"http://downloader.example.com/myfile/Josh.mp4\";";
    preg_match('/FileID(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $stringURL,$matches);
    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        $myurl = $matches[0];
    } else {
        $myurl = "http://";
    }
echo $myurl;
?>
```

Comment: Try `$myurl = $matches[3];`.

Comment: Or `print_r($matches)` and find a proper key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not it like this?

```
   preg_match('/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i', $stringURL,$matches);
```

Comment: `:` and `"` don't need to be escaped.